# How to ensure functions are run in specific order?

Tags: python, function, class, design-patterns

Im relatively new to python design patterns but I want to ensure my code is as understandable and flexible as possible. Here is an example:

```
data=query_data(sql)

transformed_data=transform_data(data, arg1, arg2)

train, test, validate = train_test_validate(transformed_data, frac_test, frac_validate)

model = fit_model(train,test, loss, learning_rate)

predictions, f1 = model.predict(validate)
```

Each function must run in this order. In this particular example the order should be very obvious. But in more complex modules there can be branching paths and it can be unclear without extensive documentation which order the functions should be run in.

It is simple enough to just wrap the module in another function that applies the functions in order but that seems to make a needlessly complex function with many arguments that violates single responsibility.

I've also tried to wrap each function in a class that returns the next class in the sequence which has the appropriate branching methods. This has the advantage that the order of the code is implied in the design of module and methods are only callable at appropriate times. This leads to many many classes, most with just one method where there are no branches. Ive been warned that this is a bad design pattern.

Is there a best way to ensure that code runs in a specific order and that that order is obvious from the design of the code?

Comment: Order always runs from top to bottom, taking time for any function calls (unless you're using threads, etc).

Comment: Classes seem like the best way to go for this. Create a class and in the `__init__` function, call all other functions for the object that are relevant. Then create other functions that may be needed inside the class.

Comment: Add a module level docstring with example usage? If the functions are properly decoupled without global state involved, it shouldn't really be a problem if they call them out of order, as long as they have valid inputs for each stage (however they are derived).

Comment: @Recessive So in this case I would have a class Model with functions query_data, transform_data, train_test_validate, fit_model and then maybe predict. If I were to call all of these in the init method wouldn't that leave me with effectively a function call with tons of parameters and possibly many outputs? Otherwise grouping them all in a class seems like it makes sense but doesnt really seem to imply an ordering to the methods. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ShadowRanger I think that is a good idea, in addition to implying order within the code structure. Im just concerned that in a confusing process it would be difficult to trace whether or not you have a valid input.  For a more specific example Im thinking of a specific package where in one class you can create a dense or a sparse matrix. The sparse matrix is an invalid input to one model type but valid for another (a fact that I couldn't find documented and wasted an hour figuring out). I want to make sure that a user of my code is aware structurally that this pathway doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user3798650 I think given these functions could be quite large and confusing in a single file (by the looks of it), it could be better to create a/multiple separate python file(s) with these functions and import it to a master file. In the master file you can very clearly and concisely go through the order as everything yucky is handled in the other python files. This can be really useful for indicating a clear order.

Comment: @Recessive I think that makes sense, and I hadn't thought about how separating modules could hint at their usage. Then I can provide examples with the if __name__ == 'main' statements. I think I may be overthinking things a bit. I was inspired reading about DAGs and it made me reconsider the readability and reusability of my code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using the common method to deal with call of functions order: pass a token from a function to another:

```
token1 = func1(token0)
token2 = func2(token1)
token3 = func2(token2)
...
```

Usually, tokens are also useful results. In your example: you won't call `transform_data` if you don't have `data` to give to it: `data` is the `token0`. Thus, `transform_data` will be called **after** `query_data`.

But I think the real problem you are dealing with is different: you fear that the user gives the wrong input to the next function, and that the function might accept it and return a wrong result:

> Im just concerned that in a confusing process it would be difficult to trace whether or not you have a valid input... The sparse matrix is an invalid input to one model type but valid for another *(comments)*

In statically typed languages, it won't (generally) happen, because the program won't compile if you give a rabbit when a cat is expected. In python, with the duck typing, it's not so easy. Let's see how you can enforce this:

- a good documentation
- check the input data
- group the functions
- lock some parameters

## Good documentation

This by far the best solution. Every one is a grown-up here. Don't worry too much.

You can use Python [typing abilities](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) for human information.

## Check the input data

This is a variation on [Defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming). If needed, wrap functions you don't own:

```
def wrap_transform_data(data, arg1, arg2):
    if not valid(data): # find a way to check this
        raise Exception("data is not valid")
    return transform_data(data, arg1, arg2)
```

Use exceptions and avoid `try... except` block since a fail fast is better here.

This won't be enough sometimes. Imagine you have a square matrix: how do you check if it was transposed before the next function call?

## Group the functions

> It is simple enough to just wrap the module in another function that applies the functions in order but that seems to make a needlessly complex function with many arguments that violates single responsibility.

You get something like that:

```
def full_process(sql, arg1, arg2, frac_test, frac_validate, loss, learning_rate):
    data=query_data(sql)
    transformed_data=transform_data(data, arg1, arg2)
    train, test, validate = train_test_validate(transformed_data, frac_test, frac_validate)
    model = fit_model(train,test, loss, learning_rate)
    predictions, f1 = model.predict(validate)
    return ...
```

As you stated, the `full_process` method has a lot of mixed parameters. The usual way to deal with this in Python is to use default values:

```
def full_process(sql, arg1=1, arg2=2, frac_test=0.7, frac_validate=0.5, loss=0.2, learning_rate=0.1):
    data=query_data(sql)
    transformed_data=transform_data(data, arg1, arg2)
    train, test, validate = train_test_validate(transformed_data, frac_test, frac_validate)
    model = fit_model(train,test, loss, learning_rate)
    predictions, f1 = model.predict(validate)
    return ...
```

It becomes readable, unless you have different parameters each time:

```
full_process(sql, frac_validate=0.9)
```

This will solve the transposed matrix example above if the `transpose` function is one of the functions.

Beware: **just group the parts without branches**. Do not write something like that:

```
def full_process(sql, , case1, case2, case3, arg1=1, arg2=2, frac_test=0.7, frac_validate=0.5, loss=0.2, learning_rate=0.1):
    data=query_data(sql)
    if case1:
        transformed_data=transform_data(data, arg1, arg2)
        train, test, validate = train_test_validate(transformed_data, frac_test, frac_validate)
        if case2:
            ...
        else:
            ...
    else:
        transformed_data=transform_data2(data, arg1, arg2)
        train, test, validate = train_test_validate(transformed_data, frac_test, frac_validate)
        if case2:
            ...
        else:
            ...

    return ...
```

It's very hard to read, to maintain, and this can lead to a combinatorial explosion!

## Lock some parameters

I add this for the record, but I don't think this is a good pratice except in some specific cases. This is similar to what you've tried with classes, but with functions.

I focus on the two lines:

```
data=get_matrix()
transformed_data=transform_data(data, arg1, arg2)
```

If you want to ensure that the user will call `transform_data` with the return value of `query_data`, you can return a function:

```
def wrapped_query_data(sql):
    def ret(arg1, arg2) # you might use functools.partial 
        transform_data(data, arg1, arg2)
    return ret
```

The code is now:

```
data_transformer = wrapped_query_data(sql)
train_test_validate = data_transformer(arg1, arg2) # no way the user can twist data here
```

Obviously, if you try to generalize this, you'll need a wrapper by step and you limit the branching possibilities.

## Conclusion

> Is there a best way to ensure that code runs in a specific order and that that order is obvious from the design of the code?

Remember that Python foster every programmer to be responsible. Use methods that enforce the order of function calls only if needed.

Comment: Wow this is so much more comprehensive than I ever Imagined. Thank you this is exactly what I needed.